# Rails 3 - getting a count of returned rows for a dynamic finder method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following dynamic finder:

```
gl=GlobalList.find_by_list_id_and_global_id(2, 89)
```

Basically, I just want to see how many records are returned but:

```
gl.size
gl.count
```

don't work. Is this better done as a chained method?

thx

**Edit #1**

can do

```
if gl.nil?
```

but would like a straight count

Comment: `gl.size` and `gl.count` should work fine..

Comment: can you post the code for `find_by_list_id_and_global_id`?

Comment: `find_by_list_id_and_global_id` is the dynamic finder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're interested in is the number of matches then [`count`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#count) would probably be best:

```
n = GlobalList.count(:list_id => 2, :global_id => 89)
```